# Performing bulk language translation in a large database

Tags: php, web-services, soap, translation

My application has a 2.7 million records table with the list of all cities and villages in the world (provided by GeoNames.org). Each city has it's name in the native language. This database will be searched in an auto-complete form, but users should be able to type the city name in their own language (primarily Portuguese, since this will be a Brazilian website) and be able to locate the city (at least the most important ones).

For instance: Munich is a well-known German city. However, in the GeoNames database, it is registered as "München", the native German name. GeoNames provides an english representation of the name, but that basically strips the special characters of the city name (in this case, München becomes Munchen, not Munich).

Is there a way or service I can use to translate each of these cities names into Portuguese (or at the very least, English) and cache them in my database? I've looked into the Google Translation API, but in their TOS, automated processes are forbidden.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I found was parsing the WordPress translation files, it includes continents & cities in one of the language files.

1. Find the language you want here:
   http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language
2. Go to the language you want and download WordPress
3. Inside the zip goto: */wp-content/languages/*
   and open continents & cities file eg. "**continents-cities-nl_NL.po**"
4. In that file you'll have all the translated city names you can easily parse into your DB

I'm currently parsing the cities in PHP when I'm finished I can post the translated files here if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the portuguese translation files have very few cities translated. We've since resorted to adding aliases manually (by hiring someone to identify top cities and add their known names).

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing Wikipedia? I often use the "Languages" menu as a dictionary. It would take some time but since this is a one-time operation it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I don't know how well is Geography covered in the Portuguese Wiki though, you have to see yourself (I only learnt that language for a short time :) ).